# Matlab - regression

Tags: matlab, regression

I am getting Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision. Adittionally, the coefficients I am getting are complex numbers, even though the input is all real. Why is this happening? Any idea how to get out of this?

Comment: Can you show us what function you're calling?

Comment: [b, bint, r, rint, stats] = regress (output, input); Is this enough? output and input are loaded from a file more or less. size (output) =   877835           1             size(input) = 877835     8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that your input vector has too many linearly dependent columns.  Do a `rank(input)` and see what the output says.  If it's less than 8, you need to remove some of your independent variables that are found in your `input` matrix.  Also, you may want to include more information on how you arrived at your `input` matrix like:

```
input = [ fuel engine_speed fuel.*engine_speed ];  % or even
input = [ x1 x2 x1.*x2 ];
```

If you have a low rank matrix, try to find the dependent columns.  Here's a quick way, that I would recommend(I'm sure someone knows of a better):

```
[R,jb] = rref(input);
full_rank_input = input(:,jb);
rank(input)
```

Should give you a matrix with `rank(full_rank_input) == num_columns`.

Comment: I got rank = 4, so very small. Maybe I have too many data points? What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have too many data points, you have too many X variables.  You need to choose which ones to remove.

Comment: This is really a statistics question (not a programming question) - maybe it would do better on the statistics Stack Exchange?